# Callable statement taking lot of time when passing * as an parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

I have the following piece of code. When I pass normal strings like "firstname lastname". The stored procedure returns within no time. but when I call it with firstname* , it takes lot of time. When I execute the stored procedure with the firstname* , it doesn't take more than 2 seconds. Here is the code below

```
public List<NameBean> getNameReportJson(final int numberOfResults,
        final String searchValue, final String category, Connection con)
        throws SQLException {

    final List<NameBean> beanList = new ArrayList();
    List<String> resultStrs = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String nameReportStoreProcedure = "{call [sp_SENTRY_INFORMATION_REPORT_NAME_REPORT] (?,?,?,?,?)}";

    Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    session.doWork(new Work() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            CallableStatement cstmt = connection
                    .prepareCall(nameReportStoreProcedure);
            ResultSet rs = null;

            cstmt.setInt("numberOfResults", numberOfResults);
            cstmt.setString("SearchValue", searchValue);
            cstmt.setString("Category", category);
            cstmt.setDate("startDate", null);
            cstmt.setDate("endDate", null);

            rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
            logger.debug("CeReport the ResultSet is: " + rs);
            while (rs.next()) {
                NameBean nameBean = new NameBean();
                String oriName = rs.getString("ORIGINAL NAME");
                String standName = rs.getString("STANDARDIZED NAME");
                String groupName = rs.getString("GROUP NAME");
                long groupId = rs.getLong("GROUP ID");
                nameBean.setOriginalName(oriName);
                nameBean.setStandardName(standName);
                nameBean.setGroupName(groupName);
                nameBean.setGroupID(groupId);
                nameBean.setEntityID(rs.getString("ENTITY ID"));
                beanList.add(nameBean);
            }

        }

    });

    return beanList;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it comes from the type of transaction configured in your application, we are missing some information...

Comment: I don't see any transactions anywhere. I looked at the stored procedure and its a bunch of selects with joins. Also this is in a web app which has a REST endpoint that's about it

Comment: nothing else running on the db? what is the db? Have you tried to change the jdbc driver? In fact, could you check there is no delay to establish the connection to the db?

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause. The issue was happening when there were simultaneous requests to the stored procedure. The culprit was the statement

```
Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
```

so what I had to do was for each request create a new instance of EntityManager and then get the session using that. Since the Session was being shared by multiple threads it was locking the tables and hence the issue. I hope this helps other people